# geolocation search box not showing suggestions

Tags: javascript, google-api

i have installed this geolocation api in my page to search a user's current location and then show route to the destination, but i also want it to show suggestions when a user type the destination in the search box

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?     sensor=false"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">  
</script>  
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
     async defer></script>
<script>
function initAutocomplete() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MyMapLOC"),  mapOptions);
});
var input = document.getElementById('txtDestination');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
}
</script> 
<%--Getting User Current Location--%>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    if (navigator.geolocation) {  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);  
    } else {  
        alert("There is Some Problem on your current browser to get Geo Location!");  
    }  

    function success(position) {  
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;  
        var long = position.coords.longitude;  
        var city = position.coords.locality;  
        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);  
        var mapOptions = {  
            center: LatLng,  
            zoom: 12,  
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
        };  

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MyMapLOC"), mapOptions);  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position: LatLng,  
            title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:      </b><br />Latitude: "  
                        + lat + +"<br />Longitude: " + long  
        });  

        marker.setMap(map);  
        var getInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>Your  Current Location</b><br/> Latitude:" +  
                                lat + "<br /> Longitude:" + long + ""  
        });  
        getInfoWindow.open(map, marker);  
    }  
</script>  

<%--Getting Route Direction From User Current Location to Destination--%>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function SearchRoute() {  
        document.getElementById("MyMapLOC").style.display = 'none';  

        var markers = new Array();  
        var myLatLng;  

        //Find the current location of the user.  
        if (navigator.geolocation) {  
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {  
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);  
                var m = {};  
                m.title = "Your Current Location";  
                m.lat = p.coords.latitude;  
                m.lng = p.coords.longitude;  
                markers.push(m);  

                //Find Destination address location.  
                var address = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;  
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {  
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {  
                        m = {};  
                        m.title = address;  
                        m.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();  
                        m.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();  
                        markers.push(m);  
                        var mapOptions = {  
                            center: myLatLng,  
                            zoom: 4,  
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
                        };  
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapRoute"), mapOptions);  
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
                        var lat_lng = new Array();  
                        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  

                        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
                            var data = markers[i];  
                            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);  
                            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);  
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
                                position: myLatlng,  
                                map: map,  
                                title: data.title  
                            });  
                            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);  
                            (function(marker, data) {  
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {  
                                    infoWindow.setContent(data.title);  
                                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);  
                                });  
                            })(marker, data);  
                        }  
                        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());  
                        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);  

                        //***********ROUTING****************//  

                        //Initialize the Path Array.  
                        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();  

                        //Getting the Direction Service.  
                        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  

                        //Set the Path Stroke Color.  
                        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });  

                        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP.  
                        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {  
                            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {  
                                var src = lat_lng[i];  
                                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];  
                                path.push(src);  
                                poly.setPath(path);  
                                service.route({  
                                    origin: src,  
                                    destination: des,  
                                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING  
                                }, function(result, status) {  
                                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {  
                                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {  
                                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);  
                                        }  
                                    } else {  
                                        alert("Invalid location.");  
                                        window.location.href = window.location.href;  
                                    }  
                                });  
                            }  
                        }  
                    } else {  
                        alert("Request failed.")  
                    }  
                });  

            });  
        }  
        else {  
            alert('Some Problem in getting Geo Location.');  
            return;  
        }  
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: what errors are showing in the developer tools console on your browser

Comment: it is not giving me any error, it is just not showing suggestions when i type in the search box

Comment: loading the maps API three times, once without the key, seems unusual to say the least

Comment: yes, look at the developer tools console and fix the multitude of errors you are getting. Don't say there are no errors, you'll be getting at least warnings about loading the API more than once, and then there's errors inside the `initAutocomplete` function regarding undefined variables, but since you're not getting any errors, you must have posted code that is not the same as the code you are having issues with

Comment: This is the error i am getting "Uncaught InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function "

Comment: a function declaration does not end with `});` ... just `}` ... that's the most obvious error - once you fix that, you'll have plenty of others to deal with, like `latLng` and `mapOptions` being undefined - and depending on where that code block is, the var input statement wont work, because it's inline, rather than within the initAutocomplete function, where it should be

Comment: actually, I see ... remove the }); line just before var input ... that'll fix that block of code partially - still have the undefined vars to deal with though